# How to keep the image of a collection that are integrally contained in a geometry boundary in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, filter, image

I have an image collection and a geometry ROI

```
var ROI = ee.Geometry.Rectangle(-78.20688664502586, 34.67650023609108, -77.65207707471336, 35.216816430066366); 

var l5 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_TOA")
      .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(1984,1985,'year'))
      .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(1,12,'month'))
      .filterBounds(ROI)
      .select('B1')
```

When I print my image collection I get 190 images. However, some of the images cover only 10% of the ROI area. I would like to keep only the images that are integral contained in ROI. I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Conceptually I believe the answer lies in the following [filter](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#eefiltercontains).  `ee.Filter.contains()` , however, I have never been able to implement it correctly.

Having said that, I do have a workaround.  If you go to the inspector tab, and then click on the images that you are interested it (the ones that contain your ROI) you can see the `WRS_PATH` and `WRS_ROW` in the metadata of the image.  They are 15 and 36 respectively.  You can then `filterMetadata()` those values giving you only the images that match that criteria.

Add this to the bottom of your code and it will only be the images that you are interested in.

```
var filtered = l5.filterMetadata("WRS_PATH","equals",15)
                 .filterMetadata("WRS_ROW","equals",36);

Map.addLayer(filtered);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ee.Filter.contains(), you have to specify the left field as '.geo':

```
var ROI = ee.Geometry.Rectangle(-78.20688664502586, 34.67650023609108, -77.65207707471336, 35.216816430066366); 

var l5 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_TOA")
      .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(1984,1985,'year'))
      .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(1,12,'month'))
      .filterBounds(ROI)
      .select('B1')
      
var filtered1 = l5.filterMetadata("WRS_PATH","equals",15)
                .filterMetadata("WRS_ROW","equals",36);
print('filter using WRS row and path', filtered1.size()) //20
var filtered2 = l5.filter(ee.Filter.contains('.geo', ROI))
print('filter using ee.Filter.contains', filtered2.size()) //20
Map.addLayer(filtered2);
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Fcaseyengstrom%2Freprex%3AfilterContains